# Deleting an Entire Line Moving Forward Shortcut

Tags: keyboard

I'd simply like to know how to delete an entire line moving forward opposite of deleting an entire line backwards (cmd + delete). I know to delete individual characters moving forwards is fn + delete but what about the deleting the entire line itself?

Comment: Try control+K. (I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure if I added it or it's there by default).

Comment: That did the trick! Feel free to post this as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> to do this. This is one of the many key bindings that OS X borrows from emacs by default. Others include <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to go to the beginning of a line, <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to go to the end of a line, and <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> as an alternate forward-delete.

Comment: Words can't describe just how in those 2 sentences you've made me that much more productive. =)

Comment: Good answer +1 for a complete answer and extra awesome shortcuts!